# How to find/install build dependencies for building GStreamer plugins?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, package-management

Is there any way to install these packages via `apt-get`?

I found none of them with `apt-cache search`.

```
aRts        (for the arts plugin wrapper, and the artsd sink)
            http://www.arts-project.org
libdvdread  (for the dvdsrc)
            http://www.dtek.chalmers.se/groups/dvd/
            (optional: libcss for encrypted DVDs)
libdvdnav   (for the dvdnavsrc)
            http://dvd.sourceforge.net/
            (optional: libcss for encrypted DVDs)
        >= 0.1.9
libgsm      (for the gsm plugin)
            http://kbs.cs.tu-berlin.de/~jutta/toast.html
sdl     (for the sdl sink)
            http://www.libsdl.org
swfdec      (for the swfdec (flash) plugin)
            http://www.schleef.org/swfdec/
dtsdec      (for DTS audio decoding)
            http://www.videolan.org/libdca.html
divx        (for divx decoding)
            http://www.divx.com/divx/linux/
musepack    (for musepack audio codec/format)
            (http://www.musepack.net/)
nas     (for the NAS sound server sink)
            (http://radscan.com/nas.html)
libmms      (for MMS protocol support)
            (http://www.sf.net/projects/libmms)
libamrnb    (for AMR-NB support)
            (http://www.penguin.cz/~utx/amr)
libamrwb    (for AMR-WB support)
            (http://www.penguin.cz/~utx/amr)
libkate     (for Kate support)
            (http://libkate.googlecode.com/)
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you really want to do (ie. compile something but what)? Maybe there's an easier way to get you where you want.

Comment: @htorque: I am installing this (http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/). And it has REQUIREMENTS file which requires those, but when i try apt-cache search thosename i get either huge list or non matched results. Which caused me 4 times of reinstalling 11.04 to 10.04. How can i exactly get those application using apt-cache search?

Comment: Is there a special reason you want to compile it yourself? Have you tried installing the Ubuntu packages `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` or `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse` instead?

Comment: @htorque: yes i did that from default package, but special reason is the default package has few elements missing does not shift, which i need to rebuild from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you try to compile a package from source that's also in Ubuntu, you can try this:

```
sudo apt-get builddep gst-plugins-bad-multiverse0.10
```

However, this does not guarantee that you will get the right versions of the dependencies in older Ubuntu releases.